# Combining/converting 2 similar object types from 2 different APIs

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I’m a beginner in C# and OOP. I’m using two 3rd party APIs that contain similar object types that have properties containing the same values, but both APIs have unique (and identical) functions that I need to use. For example:

**API1 - Point Class**

**Public Properties**

X : Double

Y : Double

**Public Method**

Distance()

ToArray()

**API2 - Point Class**

**Public Properties**

X : Double

Y : Double

**Public Method**

Project()

ToArray()

Currently I have made helper methods to convert from API1 Point class to API2 Point class and vice-versa, but there must be a better solution. What a programming expert would do in this situation? Thanks!

Comment: [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: What are you doing with the Point class from API1 and API2? Are you processing the point object from one API as input to another?

Comment: Depending on what the user does I might need to use one of the unique functions. For example API1 deals with the visualisation and UI, but has some unique functions (convert a spline to points) then I use API2 which is pure math functions to feed it the points. So I need to convert the API1 point entities into API2 point entities for the function to work. When finished API2 returns a bunch of API2 Points that I need to convert back into API1 points to show on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wrapper class and explicit conversion operation can help your problem here.

```
public class IntergratedPoint{
    // private constructor to prevent misuse
    // If want, you can do a normal constructor which create both pointApi1 and 2
    private IntergratedPoint(){ }

    // this can be set to reference either pointApi1 or 2
    public double X{get;set;} 
    public double Y{get;set;}

    private Api1.Point pointApi1;
    private Api2.Point pointApi2;

    public static explicit operator IntegratedPoint(Api1.Point pointApi1){
        IntegratedPoint newPoint = new IntegratedPoint();
        newPoint.pointApi1 = pointApi1;
        newPoint.pointApi2 = new Api1.Point();
        // set X and Y for pointApi2
    }

    // the explicit operator for Api2.Point

    public double Distance(){
        return pointApi1.Distance();
    }
    public double Project(){
        return pointApi2.Project();
    }
    public double[] ToArray(){
        // don't know what to do, but it you can do either pointApi1.ToArray() or so
    }    
}
```

Comment: Fendy, I like this approach. To make sure I fully understand. I create my own point class containing a point of each API, explicit operator and the methods I need from both APIs. Then I can use my class by casting whichever API point into my own IntergratedPoint?

Comment: Correct. This way you can use both of the class, while still keeping control of your own flow. The casting can be replaced by constructor injections, its up to youe taste though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). It gives you the ability of defining the mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>();
```

and then just use it everywhere

```
OrderDto dto = Mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
```

Comment: I don't see practical evidence of how this helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding various extension methods to the API1 Point class. With the type conversion helper methods, I can have API1 point class use API2 point class methods. With this I only use API1 point objects in my code.